# Intelligent string break: pretty print makefile output via XSLT

Tags: xslt, string

I need to pretty print some output of make via XSLT (xsltproc), with a focus on easy readability of the gcc calls (because they are the most common and important lines in said output).

Situation: I have a lot of long `<message>gcc -Wall ...</message>` nodes in my source XML file, one line of raw makefile output per `<message>` node. The output of my XSLT sheet would be HTML, putting the contents of the `<message>` nodes line by line into a `<pre>` environment. I'd like to break the string preferably on any "`-`" occurence (i.e. on the start of a command line parameter) -- if that is not found, on some characters (like `-/.:;=`), then on any whitespace; breaking the string in the middle of a string should be the last resort. I have set a global variable `$break-at` denoting the maximum characters per line.

Problem: I cannot use XSLT 2.0 functions on xsltproc (or I did not find any information regarding importing them). Therefore I'm stuck with `substring-before()`, `substring-after()`, `contains()`, `substring()`, `string-length()` (sadly, `tokenize()` is not available). I do not seem to find a way to break the string on the last occurence of whitespace (or any token) right before `$break-at`.

This is an excerpt of the source XML:

```
<message priority="info"><![CDATA[/usr/bin/moc -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. main.cpp -o main.moc]]></message>
<message priority="info"><![CDATA[/tmp/Akut/work/1296322206337_e01c972b8fe9b866aded56ff5dde35c3/AspectC++/bin/linux-release/ag++ -p /tmp/Akut/work/1296322206337_e01c972b8fe9b866aded56ff5dde35c3/1297456240104_09fad65d9a05790369dd919025284109_20110211213211/qt-examples --Xcompiler -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -o main.o main.cpp]]></message>
<message priority="info"><![CDATA[/tmp/main.cpp_agxx_c5k6Om: In destructor 'AC::ResultBuffer<T>::~ResultBuffer() [with T = QRectF]':]]></message>
<message priority="info"><![CDATA[/tmp/main.cpp_agxx_c5k6Om:216:33:   instantiated from here]]></message>
<message priority="info"><![CDATA[/tmp/main.cpp_agxx_c5k6Om:26:24: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules]]></message>
```

This is the calling XSLT code, calling the `break-string` template on every line of output:

```
<pre>
  <xsl:for-each select="message">
    <xsl:call-template name="break-string">
      <xsl:with-param name="string" select="./text()"/>      
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:for-each>
</pre>
```

This is my `break-string` template so far -- not satisfactory yet!

```
<xsl:template name="break-string">
  <xsl:param name="string" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length($string) &lt;= $break-at">
      <xsl:value-of select="$string"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, ' -')">
          <xsl:variable name="out" select="substring-before($string, ' -')"/>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($out) &lt;= $break-at">
               <xsl:value-of select="$out"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:call-template name="break-string">
                <xsl:with-param name="string"
                                select="$out" />
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
          <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
          <span class="indent"><xsl:text><![CDATA[  ]]></xsl:text></span><xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
          <xsl:call-template name="break-string">
            <xsl:with-param name="string"
                            select="substring-after($string, ' -')" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 1, $break-at)" /><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
          <span class="indent"><xsl:text><![CDATA[  ]]></xsl:text></span>
          <xsl:call-template name="break-string">
            <xsl:with-param name="string"
                            select="substring($string, $break-at + 1)" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

What's the most elegant method to break these strings?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution. :)

Comment: +1 Interesting question. In addition to @Dimitre very good answer, see mine without extensions functions.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my own without extensions:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="pSeparators" select="'&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;&#x20;-/.:;='"/>
    <xsl:param name="pMaxLength" select="64"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="message">
        <pre>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize"/>
        </pre>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:param name="pString" select="string()"/>
        <xsl:param name="pMask"
                   select="translate(.,translate(.,$pSeparators,''),'')"/>
        <xsl:param name="pLength" select="0"/>
        <xsl:param name="pTail"/>
        <xsl:if test="$pString">
            <xsl:variable name="vSeparator"
                          select="substring($pMask,1,1)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="vString"
                          select="concat(
                                     $pTail,
                                     substring-before(
                                        $pString,
                                        $vSeparator
                                     ),
                                     substring(
                                        $pString,
                                        1 div not($vSeparator)
                                     )
                                  )"/>
            <xsl:variable name="vLength"
                          select="string-length($vString)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="vMaxLength"
                          select="$pMaxLength - $pLength"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$vMaxLength >= $vLength">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$vString"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pString"
                             select="substring(
                                        substring-after($pString,$vSeparator),
                                        1 div boolean($vSeparator))"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pMask"
                             select="substring($pMask,2)"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pLength"
                             select="$pLength + $vLength"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pTail" select="$vSeparator"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="string-length(
                                   normalize-space($vString)
                                ) > $pMaxLength">
                    <xsl:value-of
                         select="concat(
                                    substring(
                                       $vString, 1, $vMaxLength
                                    ),
                                    '&#xA;'
                                 )"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pString"
                             select="substring(
                                        $pString,
                                        $vMaxLength - string-length($pTail) +1
                                     )"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pMask" select="$pMask"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;',
                                                 normalize-space($vString))"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pString"
                             select="substring(
                                        substring-after($pString,$vSeparator),
                                        1 div boolean($vSeparator))"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pMask"
                             select="substring($pMask,2)"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pLength" select="$vLength"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pTail" select="$vSeparator"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<t>
    <message priority="info"><![CDATA[/usr/bin/moc -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. main.cpp -o main.moc]]></message>
    <message priority="info"><![CDATA[/tmp/Akut/work/1296322206337_e01c972b8fe9b866aded56ff5dde35c3/AspectC++/bin/linux-release/ag++ -p /tmp/Akut/work/1296322206337_e01c972b8fe9b866aded56ff5dde35c3/1297456240104_09fad65d9a05790369dd919025284109_20110211213211/qt-examples --Xcompiler -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -o main.o main.cpp]]></message>
    <message priority="info"><![CDATA[/tmp/main.cpp_agxx_c5k6Om: In destructor 'AC::ResultBuffer<T>::~ResultBuffer() [with T = QRectF]':]]></message>
    <message priority="info"><![CDATA[/tmp/main.cpp_agxx_c5k6Om:216:33:   instantiated from here]]></message>
    <message priority="info"><![CDATA[/tmp/main.cpp_agxx_c5k6Om:26:24: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules]]></message>
</t>
```

Output:

```
<t><pre>/usr/bin/moc -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB 
-DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr
/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 
-I. main.cpp -o main.moc</pre><pre>/tmp/Akut/work/1296322206337_e01c972b8fe9b866aded56ff5dde35c3
/AspectC++/bin/linux-release/ag++ -p /tmp/Akut/work
/1296322206337_e01c972b8fe9b866aded56ff5dde35c3
/1297456240104_09fad65d9a05790369dd919025284109_20110211213211
/qt-examples --Xcompiler -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT 
-DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr
/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I
/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -o main.o main.cpp</pre><pre>/tmp/main.cpp_agxx_c5k6Om: In destructor 'AC::ResultBuffer&lt;T&gt;:
:~ResultBuffer() [with T = QRectF]'</pre><pre>/tmp/main.cpp_agxx_c5k6Om:216:33:   instantiated from here</pre><pre>/tmp/main.cpp_agxx_c5k6Om:26:24: warning: dereferencing type
-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules</pre></t>
```

Rendered:

```
/usr/bin/moc -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB 
-DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr
/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 
-I. main.cpp -o main.moc
```

```
/tmp/Akut/work/1296322206337_e01c972b8fe9b866aded56ff5dde35c3
/AspectC++/bin/linux-release/ag++ -p /tmp/Akut/work
/1296322206337_e01c972b8fe9b866aded56ff5dde35c3
/1297456240104_09fad65d9a05790369dd919025284109_20110211213211
/qt-examples --Xcompiler -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT 
-DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr
/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I
/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -o main.o main.cpp
```

```
/tmp/main.cpp_agxx_c5k6Om: In destructor 'AC::ResultBuffer<T>:
:~ResultBuffer() [with T = QRectF]'
```

```
/tmp/main.cpp_agxx_c5k6Om:216:33:   instantiated from here
```

```
/tmp/main.cpp_agxx_c5k6Om:26:24: warning: dereferencing type
-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
```

**Note**: The basic is the multi delimiters tokenizetion "tailing" the delimiter (because it looks like you want to keep the delimiter with the next item). I didn't give too much time, but the breaking logic migth be simplify further. Now there are three cases: item fits in current line, item doesn't fit in full line (break item), item doesn't fit in current line but it fits in new line (new line, don't break item).

Comment: @Alejandro. +1 for the effort :) As you know, users of FXSL save a lot of effort and are not given the chance to commit endless and repeating errors that would be the case if they had to write themselves what is provided by FXSL.

Comment: @Dimitre: Thanks! It wasn't too much effort... I think I've used the multi delimiter tokenizer in three answers in a week. But do note that requeriments include **breaking words** as last resource. I know that this would be an edge case (when word doesn't fit in a full line) but I thought I had to add this to the breaking logic.

Comment: Oh My..., I wrote +1 12 hrs ago and obviously forgot to do it. Fixed no. :)

Comment: @Alejandro: I think my solution doesn't break words at all.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the existing `str-split-to-lines` template from FXSL**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:str-split2lines-func="f:str-split2lines-func"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl ext str-split2lines-func"
>


   <xsl:import href="dvc-str-foldl.xsl"/>

   <str-split2lines-func:str-split2lines-func/>

   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-lines">
        <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="/*"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pLineLength" select="64"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters" select="' &#9;&#10;&#13;'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="str-split-to-lines">
      <xsl:param name="pStr"/>
      <xsl:param name="pLineLength" select="60"/>
      <xsl:param name="pDelimiters" select="' &#9;&#10;&#13;'"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vsplit2linesFun"
                    select="document('')/*/str-split2lines-func:*[1]"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vrtfParams">
       <delimiters><xsl:value-of select="$pDelimiters"/></delimiters>
       <lineLength><xsl:copy-of select="$pLineLength"/></lineLength>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:variable name="vResult">
          <xsl:call-template name="dvc-str-foldl">
            <xsl:with-param name="pFunc" select="$vsplit2linesFun"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="$pStr"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pA0" select="ext:node-set($vrtfParams)"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:for-each select="ext:node-set($vResult)/line">
        <xsl:for-each select="word">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="str-split2lines-func:*">
      <xsl:param name="arg1" select="/.."/>
      <xsl:param name="arg2"/>

      <xsl:copy-of select="$arg1/*[position() &lt; 3]"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$arg1/line[position() != last()]"/>

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($arg1/*[1], $arg2)">
          <xsl:if test="string($arg1/word)">
             <xsl:call-template name="fillLine">
               <xsl:with-param name="pLine" select="$arg1/line[last()]"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="pWord" select="$arg1/word"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="pLineLength" select="$arg1/*[2]"/>
             </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$arg1/line[last()]"/>
          <word><xsl:value-of select="concat($arg1/word, $arg2)"/></word>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

      <!-- Test if the new word fits into the last line -->
    <xsl:template name="fillLine">
      <xsl:param name="pLine" select="/.."/>
      <xsl:param name="pWord" select="/.."/>
      <xsl:param name="pLineLength" />

      <xsl:variable name="vnWordsInLine" select="count($pLine/word)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="vLineLength" 
       select="string-length($pLine) + $vnWordsInLine"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not($vLineLength + string-length($pWord) 
                           > 
                            $pLineLength)">
          <line>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pLine/*"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pWord"/>
          </line>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$pLine"/>
          <line>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pWord"/>
          </line>
          <word/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on this XML document (your XML's first element):**

```
<message priority="info"><![CDATA[/usr/bin/moc -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. main.cpp -o main.moc]]></message>
```

**the wanted, correct result (split to lines with max. length 64) is produced:**

```
/usr/bin/moc -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB 
-DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. 
-I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui 
-I/usr/include/qt4 -I. main.cpp -o
```

Comment: looks like that's the answer ... I just cannot test it right now. You'll have to wait a bit for the green checkmark :)

Comment: @maligree: No problem, you are welcome. And please, ask any questions if you need additional assistance.

Comment: @Dimitre: Okay, I finally got around to trying it out. On the first call of your template, xsltproc bails out with `XPath error : Invalid type`. I suspect the culprit to be `select="ext:node-set($vrtfParams)"`, although I'm still a bit hazy about copy&paste errors (I already edited some `>` to `&gt;`). And I'm still unsure about having the same version of dvc-str-foldl.xsl as you ...

Comment: @maligree:If your XSLT 1.0 processor doesn't implement the EXSLT `xxx:node-set()` extension function, FXSL has also an MSXML, and Xalan editions that you may download from sourceforge as zipped archives. The power of having and using FXSL is that it has some extremely useful and ready-for-you templates/functions, such as `str-split-to-lines` and `str-foldl` in this case , that you can "just use" without having even to think. This reduces the development time by many factors of magnitude.

Comment: @maligree: As for escaping the `>` character -- it is not necessary at all and I don't recommend it as this makes the code a lot unreadable.

Comment: As I said: I use xsltproc (http://xmlsoft.org/xslt/xsltproc.html), therefore none of these options apply (as far as I can see).

Comment: @Dimitre: And as for escaping the `>` character: It may not be necessary, but my xml syntax highlighter looks funny when it's not escaped (there's a bug in the syntax highlighter, I assume).

Comment: @maligree: Then don't use this syntax hi-lighter. As alternative, why don't you have a look at the XPath Visualizer (hosted at: http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html), which besides being a good XPath learning tool also provides a nice XML pretty-printed display?